# Exp-resso Store Orphaned Products after Channel Field Removed

Tags: expresso-store

**Scenario:**

- Add an Exp-resso Store Product field to an existing channel field
  group.
- Populate the product data for every entry in that channel.
- Delete the store custom field from the channel field group

**The Problem**

Store still thinks these products exist. They still show up in the Inventory page and the old entries (that used to have a product field) show up in all the "match product" fields for setting up discounts, etc..

**Why**

When deleting the store custom field from the channel field group, it seems that the corresponding entries in the Exp-resso Store Products database table should be deleted too, but they are not.

**Question**

Is there a way to remove a Store Custom Field from a Channel Field Group that will cause the corresponding entries in the Store Products database table to be deleted?

Comment: What version of Exp-resso Store are you running?

Comment: EE 2.8.1, Store 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there aren't any EE hooks which run when a channel or channel field is deleted, so there is no easy way for Store to clean these up.

You could do it yourself in the database using a SQL query like this:

```
delete from exp_store_products
where entry_id not in (
    select entry_id from exp_channel_titles
)
```

Comment: Interesting to know. This brings up a host of other questions about orphaned data, but I'll post another topic for that.